# Writing binary file in C++, unsigned char is too small but other data types add padding, is there an alternative?

Tags: c++, binary, alignment

I'm trying to write a .bmp in C++ but unsigned char can't hold a value high enough for my needs and other data types add padding because of specific byte alignment that makes a mess of things. So is there an alternative data type that can hold a higher value that won't add padding (or a way to make unsigned char hold a higher value)?

Comment: What padding?  Do you mean something like `struct Pixel {BYTE red; BYTE green; BYTE blue}` having a size of 4 for alignment reasons?

Answer (score 2):

If you write your data in an array first, there is no padding.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you are misunderstanding how data is stored.

If you have a bmp image in memory it may be kept in an internal structure (struct/class) however you can serialize that to an array of unsigned chars (bytes) which you write to a file. A file opened in binary mode doesn't add anything more than what you write.

[see](http://www.angelfire.com/country/aldev0/cpphowto/cpp_BinaryFileIO.html)